# Is it possible to use GPG to decrypt a file to stdout without parasite info (such as key used, prompt for password)

Tags: bash-scripting, gnupg

I've been searching for days, but so far, no luck. Maybe I'm searching with the bad keywords.

I need to use GPG to **decrypt** encrypted **file in memory**, without writing decrypted contents to disk.

A third party software will call a script shell providing encrypted content as `stdin` and passphrase as a parameter.
For test purpose only, I've read a shell variable

```
read pass
```

then I typed in my passphrase.

```
echo $pass | gpg  --passphrase-fd 0 --no-comment -q --no-verbose --decrypt fichier.chiffre.armor.gpg
```

this yields

```
You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Myself <fake@gpg-test.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 5F65F788, created 2019-02-22 (main key ID C7E00AC4)

message secret
```

I wish to get only `message secret`, not the previous text related to decryption.

If I call `echo $pass | gpg  --passphrase-fd 0 --no-comment -q --no-verbose --output decrypted.txt --decrypt fichier.chiffre.armor.gpg` the file `decrypted.txt`contains only `message secret`

I've tried to use `/dev/stdout` as -`-output` parameter, but it was a failure.

```
echo $pass | gpg  --passphrase-fd 0 --no-comment -q --no-verbose --output /dev/stdout --decrypt fichier.chiffre.armor.gpg


You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Myself <fake@gpg-test.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 5F65F788, created 2019-02-22 (main key ID C7E00AC4)

File `/dev/stdout' exists. Overwrite? (y/N)
```

Any idea on how to this using GPG only ?

Thanks,
Sebastien

Comment: What happened with `--output` & /dev/stdout that failed?

Comment: @Xen2050 the system ask me if I want to overwrite /dev/stdout

I've edited my question with what happen


You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Myself <fake@gpg-test.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 5F65F788, created 2019-02-22 (main key ID C7E00AC4)

File \`/dev/stdout' exists. Overwrite? (y/N)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gpg doesn't seem to output info messages similar to yours, especially with `-q`, but anyway if as you say the only problem is you're getting extra messages from stderr, you can eliminate them (by redirecting stderr to /dev/null) by adding this to your command:

```
2>/dev/null
```

And you can go back to using stdout & don't have to worry about securely wiping any temporary files containing decrypted info.

---

[Also, `--pinentry-mode loopback` might be useful for avoiding some prompts]

Answer (score 0):

actually the part

```
You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Myself <fake@gpg-test.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 5F65F788, created 2019-02-22 (main key ID C7E00AC4)
```

isn't written on `stdout`.

When piping original command to `sed 1,5d` hoping to remove the first 5 lines, it just removed the cleartext message.

by redirecting the output to a file we got what we need :

```
myself@myhost:~/gpg$ echo $pass | gpg  --passphrase-fd 0 --no-comment -q --no-verbose --decrypt fichier.chiffre.armor.gpg > toto.txt


You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Myself <fake@gpg-test.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 5F65F788, created 2019-02-22 (main key ID C7E00AC4)

myself@myhost:~/gpg$ cat toto.txt
message secret
```

I've confused `stdout` with what is written on the screen.

Comment: also using `--no-tty`do exactly what I wanted at first